# Need a solution for circular dependency in C++/CLI (compiler error)

Tags: compiler-errors, c++-cli, circular-dependency

I'm trying to resolve the following in C++/CLI which creates a circular dependency. Meaning the way it compiles, the class does not exist yet when in EventHandler; but the class needs to create an EventHandler, and thus the order of classes cannot be reversed either.

I have reasons for both classes to have references to each other, but the compiler won't recognize the classes. (i.e. compiler error).

Comment: The C++/CLI compiler inherited the seventies single-pass compile model.  All types must be know to the compiler at the point where they are used.  Google 'C++ incomplete type' and split the declaration from the definition to survive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solve this the same way you would in ordinary C++: you first declare the type and its functions, then use them, and only define them after that, outside of the rest of the type's code. So, if you want to have everything in one file (and not deal with header files etc.), you could do something like:

```
public ref class EventHandler
{
public:
    EventHandler(){} 

    void DataChanged(Object^ sender, DataTableEventArgs ^arg);
};

public ref class DTManager
{
    // all of DTManager's code goes here; you can use EventHandler::DataChanged
};

void EventHandler::DataChanged(Object^ sender, DataTableEventArgs ^arg);
{
    DTManager::DataChanged(arg);
}
```

The normal C++ way is to declare all types and their functions in header files and put only their definitions into code files. Doing it this way is much easier for big projects, especially if you have circular dependencies.

Comment: hmm I might be doing something wrong, but I'm getting this error: Error 3 error C3767: 'MyNamespace::DTManager::DataChanged': candidate function(s) not accessible

Comment: You are right! I forgot to use public before DTManager::DataChanged. :D

Also, could you enlighten me on the error I received? Why is it called a candidate function if there is no public?

Comment: I think that's just how the part of compiler that chooses which method to call works: first take all methods with the correct name and then remove those that are not accessible. Not the other way around. In this case, I think it worked in your favor, because you probably wouldn't get as good error message otherwise.